# Hide controls of one groupbox by another groupbox in VC++ MFC in Visual studio 2013

Tags: mfc

I have 5 controls in a group box created in VC++ MFC in Visual studio 2013. So by using another group box I want to hide the controls of the previous group box.
I tried by making another group box as non transparent but it did not work :(

Can anyone help me please ?

Sid

Answer (score 2):

Group boxes do not have any effect on the controls within. They are just a decoration. What you may want  is to put the 5 controls on a child modeless dialog that is positioned on the main dialog. Then you can have another child dialog with different controls, or no controls. Make one child dialog visible and the other invisible (by calling ShowWindow) to show or hide the 5 controls.

This is the way complex dialogs like a tabbed set of pages is done.